# Laravel 7: Divide database results into 3-row results and put each into bootstrap4 row

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

Hello I was wondering if it's possible to use bootstrap rows when extracting data from the database. I have made a layout(3 colums) and I want to display the database results in the rows. I want to have 3 rows of 3 items each on every page so that's what I created in the PostController.php file:

```
public function index(Post $post)
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(9);
        return view('admin.posts.viewposts', [
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }
```

And it works perfectly. But the problem is, it displays the posts in one line (one in every row). I want to have 3x3 post layout using bootstrap4. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, you could use the Collection's [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-chunk) method.

> [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-chunk)
>
> The chunk method breaks the collection into multiple, smaller collections of a given size:
>
> ```php
> $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
>
> $chunks = $collection->chunk(4);
>
> $chunks->toArray();
>
> // [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
> ```
>
> This method is especially useful in [views](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views) when working with a grid system such as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). Imagine you have a collection of [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) models you want to display in a grid:
>
> ```xml
> @foreach ($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
>     <div class="row">
>         @foreach ($chunk as $product)
>             <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
>         @endforeach
>     </div>
> @endforeach
> ```

You could do the following:

#### Controller

```php
public function index(Post $post)
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

    return view('admin.posts.viewposts', [
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
}
```

#### View

```xml
<!-- Posts Layout -->
<div class="container">
  @foreach ($posts->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <!-- Layout for 3 posts -->
    <div class="row">
      @foreach ($chunk as $post)
        <!-- Layout for a single post -->
        <div class="col">
          <h3>{{ $post->... }}</h3>
          <h3>{{ $post->... }}</h3>
          <h3>{{ $post->... }}</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- End Layout for a single post -->
      @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- End Layout for 3 posts -->
  @endforeach
</div>
<!-- End Posts Layout -->
```